# Can't return scheduling priority of thread in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I've been working on a tough assignment that requires a lot of research, and I've hit a dead end. I've been reading the man pages for linux but I'm having a hard time absorbing any of the information there. This is my third week programming in C.

I've managed to create a new thread, and set it's scheduling priority to SCHED_FIFO. In my program I create it, tell it to wait two seconds, and then once it's done I try to print out what priority I gave it (so basically, I want it to print out "policy = SCHED_FIFO"). I'm going to have to do this for SCHED_OTHER as well, but that should be easy enough to do on my own once I understand this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *FIFORunner(void *vargp, pthread_t thread);


int main(){
    pthread_t myThread;
    printf("Before Thread\n\n");

    pthread_create(&myThread, NULL, FIFORunner, NULL);

    pthread_join(myThread, NULL);

    printf("After Thread\n");

    return 0;
} 



void *FIFORunner(void *vargp, pthread_t myThread){

   int s, policy;

   struct sched_param param;

   pthread_setschedparam(&myThread, SCHED_FIFO, &param);

   sleep(2);

   s = pthread_getschedparam(myThread, &policy, &param);

   printf("policy = %d\n", policy);
   return NULL;
}
```

So there's my code, nothing that fancy. Whenever I run this, it prints out a seemingly random integer, such as: policy = 1464624896, policy = -1630095616, and policy = 1487660800.

How can I get pthread_getschedparam() to work? Am I passing in the wrong things?

Comment: @user3629249 First point is valid. Second is valid. Third (unused argument) is subjective code style that differs between organizations. Fourth is valid and will most likely explain the problem. Fifth is simply not valid, check the man page for `pthread_create`.

Comment: @immibis,  Any organization that accepts code that does not cleanly compile is begging for failure. So the warning, from the compiler, of `unused argument` is NOT 'subjective code style`  However, wither using `pthread_exit()` or `return`  could be considered coding style.

Comment: @immibis,  I moved my comments to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. will fail if trying to raise the priority or scheduling levels
4. properly checks for errors
5. once you have this basic code, you can experiment to try and raise the `priority` and/or the `scheduling` levels.
6. suggest making priority and/or scheduling level settings in the 'attributes' parameter when the thread was created as raising those values inside the thread does not work
7. this is the syntax for a thread function: `void *(*start_routine) (void *)` Note that there is only 1 parameter, not two. Therefore, the OPs posted code does not compile. (that is not the only reason)
8. regarding: pthread_setschedparam(&myThread, SCHED_FIFO, &param); the variable `myThread` is a local variable in the function `main()`, so is not visible outside the scope of main(). The result is the posted code does not compile.
9. regarding: void *FIFORunner(void *vargp) the parameter vargp is not used. This result in the compiler outputting a warning message. to eliminate the warning message, the first line in the function should be: `(void)vargp;`
10. for both: `pthread_setschedparam(&myThread, SCHED_FIFO, &param);` and `s = pthread_getschedparam(myThread, &policy, &param);` the returned value should be checked (==0) to assure the operation was successful. If not successful, call `perror()` to output the enclosed text and the reason the system thinks the operation failed.
11. regarding: `return NULL;` this will 'work', however, a equivalent statement that stays within the `pthread` function family would be: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *FIFORunner( void *vargp );


int main( void )
{
    pthread_t myThread;
    printf("Before Thread\n\n");

    // any priority and/or scheduling changes should be
    // applied via the second parameter to 'pthread_create()'
    pthread_create( &myThread, NULL, FIFORunner, NULL);

    printf( "in main: myThread = %d\n", (int)myThread );

    pthread_join( myThread, NULL );

    printf("After Thread\n");

    return 0;
}


void *FIFORunner( void *vargp )
{
    (void)vargp;

   pthread_t myThread = pthread_self();

    int policy = SCHED_OTHER;   // any higher policy will cause 'pthread_setschedparam()` to fail.


    struct sched_param param;
    param.sched_priority = 0;   // any higher priority will cause 'pthread_setschedparam()` to fail.


    printf( "in Thread: myThread = %d\n", (int)myThread );
    if( pthread_setschedparam( myThread, policy, &param ) )
    {
        perror( "pthread_setschedparm failed" );
        pthread_exit( NULL );
    }

    sleep(2);

    if( pthread_getschedparam( myThread, &policy, &param ) )
    {
        perror( "pthread_getschedparam failed" );
        pthread_exit( NULL );
    }

    printf( "policy = %d\n", policy );
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}
```

Comment: I downvoted this because it's a code-only answer with no explanation of what the problem was or how it was fixed.

Comment: @immibis,  perhaps you missed the first 5 statements in this answer. and combined with the comments I posted clearly indicates the root of the OPs problem

Comment: I moved all my comments to the question to my answer

Comment: @immibis,  the code didn't compile, the call to: `pthread_setschedparam()` failed, the reference in the threead function to `myThread` doesn't work.  What more explanation does the OP need?

Comment: Does the call to `pthread_setschedparam` fail in your code? Does it fail in the OP's code? What did you change to make it not fail?

Comment: @immibis, it fails in the OPs code due to invalid values (like the `myThread`  field being invalid.  The OPs code fails due to trying to raise the priority and/or scheduling values.  The only thing the code, inside the thread, can do is lower or re-rise those values after lowering.   If you were to compare the two versions of the code, you can then easily see what was changed. All the function calls in the answer are successful.  Of course, passing invalid parameters will make them fail.  Have your tried running the answer?